# Android studio Google Map API with fragments

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to show a simple google map with fragment.
I try call a fragment in mainActivity:

```
MapFragment.newInstance();
```

And here is fragment class:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mapView;

    public static MapFragment newInstance() {
        return new MapFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup   container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    }
}
```

and layout fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

But when test it in my device, the app be restart.

whtas my wrong?

SOME errors:

> 01-15 05:00:54.770 23995-24019/? E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with
>   status: 10 01-15 05:00:54.770 23995-24019/? E/GMPM: Uploading is not
>   possible. App measurement disabled 01-15 05:00:55.010 23995-23995/?
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main . . . at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                         at android.view.Choreogr 01-15 05:17:00.890 3281-3460/?
>   E/InputDispatcher: channel '682f930
>   com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.sample/com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.sample.MainActivity
>   (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   01-15 05:17:00.890 3281-3731/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in
>   code is: 102 01-15 05:17:06.890 2778-2778/? E/Thermal-daemon: [pa_0]
>   temp_new :32  temp_old :33 01-15 05:17:06.890 2778-2778/?
>   E/Thermal-daemon: [charger_ic] temp_new :32  temp_old :33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment is not MapView

Change your fragment layout Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and find GoogleMap instance on your fragment

```
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
}
```

ref : https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551